# Converting string to array address

Tags: php, arrays

I have dynamically generated array `$array[]`, that could be multidimensional and I have a function that return string, which contains address in array (existing one). My question is: how to create or convert string `$a = 'array[1]'` to address `$array[1]`?

Example:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4];
$string = 'array[2]';

function magic($array, $string){
//some magic happens
return $result;

$result = magic($array, $string);
echo $result;
// and 3 is displayed;
```

Is there a function already to do this? Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It should be $string = &$array[2]; which is a reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: `echo eval('$' . $string);`

Comment: eval seems the right way to go, and maybe use a reference so you can change the value too.

Comment: Why your function returns such string but not just the index value?

Comment: It's probably because it's user input. Otherwise he could just return a reference.

Comment: My array is dynamicly generated and updated and it can be multidimensional. My function chooses random state in array. It goes throug all levels and appends the random index to whole path. If i knew how many dimensions there will be - I could just make $array[rand()]...[rand()] else i end up with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is a modification of [`ResponseBag::get()`](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/ParameterBag.php#L103) from the wonderful [`HttpFoundation`](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation) project:

```
function magic($array, $path, $default = null)
{
    if (false === $pos = strpos($path, '[')) {
        return $array;
    }

    $value = $array;
    $currentKey = null;

    for ($i = $pos, $c = strlen($path); $i < $c; $i++) {
        $char = $path[$i];

        if ('[' === $char) {
            if (null !== $currentKey) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Malformed path. Unexpected "[" at position %d.', $i));
            }

            $currentKey = '';
        } elseif (']' === $char) {
            if (null === $currentKey) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Malformed path. Unexpected "]" at position %d.', $i));
            }

            if (!is_array($value) || !array_key_exists($currentKey, $value)) {
                return $default;
            }

            $value = $value[$currentKey];
            $currentKey = null;
        } else {
            if (null === $currentKey) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Malformed path. Unexpected "%s" at position %d.', $char, $i));
            }

            $currentKey .= $char;
        }
    }

    if (null !== $currentKey) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Malformed path. Path must end with "]".'));
    }

    return $value;
}

echo magic([1,2,3,4], 'array[2]'); // 3
```

It can be modified to return a reference as well, just sprinkle it with some ampersands :)